# Python/Json Code - Where was this variable located

Tags: python, json

This code is from a separate submission.
If you look at the lines :

**each[AuthorString]**

**each[Title]**

im wondering where the user got these variables from?

I navigated to the json page
[Link](https://cdn-solr.asco.org/solr/ml/mlselect?_format=json&wt=json&indent=true&q=SessionId:13619&start=0&rows=30&sort=score%20desc,%20SessionId%20asc&fq=RecordType:sessions&facet=true&f.Year.facet.sort=index&facet.field=%7B!key=Year%7DYear&facet.field=%7B!key=subject_thes%7Dsubject_thes&facet.field=%7B!key=MediaTypes%7DMediaTypes&facet.field=%7B!key=fctSessionType%7DfctSessionType&facet.pivot=%7B!key=MeetingName%7DfctMeetingName,fctTrack&spellcheck.maxCollationTries=100)

and could not find these variables? maybe im in the wrong page? Screenshots will help

here is the code

```
 import requests

session_ids = ['13619' ,'13736']

for session_id in session_ids:
    url = 'https://cdn-solr.asco.org/solr/ml/mlselect'
    payload = '?_format=json&wt=json&indent=true&q=SessionId:' + session_id + '&start=0&rows=30&sort=score%20desc,%20SessionId%20asc&fq=RecordType:sessions&facet=true&f.Year.facet.sort=index&facet.field={!key=Year}Year&facet.field={!key=subject_thes}subject_thes&facet.field={!key=MediaTypes}MediaTypes&facet.field={!key=fctSessionType}fctSessionType&facet.pivot={!key=MeetingName}fctMeetingName,fctTrack&spellcheck.maxCollationTries=100'
    headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36'}
    
    jsonData = requests.get(url+payload, headers=headers).json()
    sessionParticipationID = jsonData['response']['docs'][0]['SessionParticipationID']
    session_id_list = '%20OR%20'.join(sessionParticipationID)
    
    
    payload = '?_format=json&wt=json&indent=true&sort=PresentationOrderWithinSession%20asc,%20ISODateString%20asc,%20ISODateStringEnd%20asc&fl=_id,%20score,%20ISODateString,%20ISODateStringEnd,%20ISODateString_1,%20ISODateStringEnd_1,%20Year,%20Title,%20tempAbstractID,%20MediaID,%20VideoID,%20EdBookID,%20edBookTitle,%20PosterID,%20edBookTitle,%20SessionTitle,%20SessionTypeId,%20AuthorString,%20AbstID,%20Role,%20FullName,%20PosterBoard,%20Institution,%20ProgramTitle,%20MeetingName,%20FirstAuthor&q=_id:(' + session_id_list + ')&rows=' + str(len(sessionParticipationID))
    
    jsonData = requests.get(url+payload, headers=headers).json()
    
    title_auth = []  #<-- to make a list of {title:author} dictionary
    for each in jsonData['response']['docs']:
        title = each['Title'] #this line
        author = each['AuthorString'] #and this
```

Comment: They likely just mixed up names, those items are not present in the JSON, so either the code is wrong or the JSON is wrong

Comment: No, the code works fine though?

Comment: Then the code is likely pulling JSON from a different source than you are

Comment: Ok so if thats the case, can you point to where the code is pointing?

Comment: Here `jsonData = requests.get(url+payload, headers=headers).json()` take note of the `payload` variable. It includes 'Title' and 'AuthorString' in the request. The json you have linked to does not include these in the request.

Comment: if you print out `url` + `payload` you'll get the correct source of the json the function uses

Comment: How does my link and the json=requests.get(url+payload,headers=headers).json() differ?

Comment: i printed them out, thats where i linked the json folder. if im not seeing/getting it, can you please attach screenshots

Comment: I see it in the payload now, thank you

Comment: The code is confusing for I did not realise there were two different payloads. I meant the second payload and not the first. Sorry for that confusion

Comment: Adding further clarification, but yes agreed this code confusing to follow. The script is creating `jsonData` from the first GET request, and grabbing `sessionParticipationID` from the response. Then they are repurposing the `jsonData` variable to store the response from a second GET request that utilizes the `sessionParticipationID` as part of the request.